# How can I use mod_rewrite to redirect URLs from one subdomain to another?

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a test web server: `abc2.example.com`. I migrated the web site: `abc1.example.com` to this test server (abc2).  All the links on abc2 are untouched and point to abc1's pages.  When I click on a link on abc2, I would like it to go to the abc2 hosted page rather than go to abc1.  How can I make all outgoing links on `abc2.example.com/anypage` go to `abc2.example.com/anypage` instead of going to `abc1.example.com/anypage`?

I've tried doing this with mod_rewrite (added to httpd.conf):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc1\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:\/\/abc2\.example\.com/$1 [R,L]
```

...but that doesn't seem to work

I want to keep the links unchanged because `abc2.example.com` will soon take over `abc1.example.com` and become the live production site.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a perfect 1:1 mapping, and the only thing between the two sites that's changing is the hostname, then you don't need mod_rewrite. A simple

```
RedirectMatch (.*) http://abc1.example.com$1
```

in the abc2 vhost definition will do the trick.